# Passing data from ListView to Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a `ListView` in my fist screen that shows some information. When I click on each item, I have another listView with new information and textview in the same page, I want to show the pervious list view row in text view,

would you please let me know how can I implement this,

Thanks in advance!

here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="######">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/no_message"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java file that shows the listview and

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  
savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_forms);

    TextView details = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.detail_header);

    details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return view;
}
```

Here is one of my fragment that has onItemClick Listener

public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

```
public static final String TAG = "ListFragment";

private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> testIds;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    tripIds = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    registerForContextMenu(listView);

    return view;
}
```

Here is my onItemClick :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    chooseTest(testIds.get(position));

    String selectedTestId = testIds.get(position);

    Helpers.saveToSharedPreferences(getActivity(),
            Constants_Prefs.SELECTED_TOP_LEVEL_RECORD,
            Constants_Keys.SELECTED_TEST_ID,


          selectedTestId);
```

I don't know how can I get that information

```
    FormTypeListFragment passDataTo = new FormTypeListFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("DATA", selectedTestId);
    passDataTo.setArguments(bundle);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before launching your fragment to display selected item use `setArguments()` method to add key value pair of string in your case, Then in your fragment on createView use fragments method `getArguments()` to retain your passed string

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value in bundle as :

### Set :

```
YourFragment fragmnt = new YourFragment ();
Bundle bundle  =  new Bundle();
bundle.putString("item","name");
fragmnt.setArgument(bundle);
```

### Get :

Then in your Fragment, retrieve the data (e.g. in onCreate()) with:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String myValue = bundle.getInt("item", "");
```

Comment: thank you for reply, is it possible, when I click on one row in listView-> onItemClick ->print all information in one textView ??

Comment: can I add it on onCreateView instead of onCreate??

Comment: You can create field in your fragment class and then in `onCreate()` assign that field, then use that value in `onCreateView()` because as far as I'am aware `onCreateView()` gets called after `onCreate()` method

Comment: May help [Fragments lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png)